# Error in range based iteration if object and iterator are in different namespace

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang, c++14

I am getting an error with custom range based iterator for one of our class with clang compiler but works fine with vc++ (2015, 2017).

I have eliminated the code down to what I see as the issue and shared at http://rextester.com/SDZO92213.

```
#define USE_NAMESPACE 1

#if USE_NAMESPACE
#define MY_NAMESPACE1 my_ns1
#define MY_NAMESPACE2 my_ns2
#else
#define MY_NAMESPACE1
#define MY_NAMESPACE2
#endif

#if USE_NAMESPACE
namespace MY_NAMESPACE1
{
#endif
    class my_cls
    {
    };
#if USE_NAMESPACE
}
#endif

#if USE_NAMESPACE
namespace MY_NAMESPACE2{
#endif

    struct my_iterator
    {
        size_t pos;

        my_iterator() = delete;

        my_iterator(size_t nPos) : pos(nPos)
        {
        }

        my_iterator(const my_iterator& that)
        {
            this->pos = that.pos;
        }

        const my_iterator& operator = (const my_iterator& that)
        {
            if(this != &that)
            {
                this->pos = that.pos;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        const size_t operator*() const
        {
            return pos;
        }

        bool operator == (const my_iterator& that) const
        {
            return this->pos == that.pos;
        }

        bool operator != (const my_iterator& that) const
        {
            return this->pos != that.pos;
        }

        my_iterator& operator++() {
            ++pos;
            return *this;
        }
    };


    inline my_iterator begin(MY_NAMESPACE1::my_cls*)
    {
        return my_iterator(0);
    }

    inline my_iterator end(MY_NAMESPACE1::my_cls*)
    {
        return my_iterator(10);
    }
#if USE_NAMESPACE
}
#endif

namespace std
{
    using MY_NAMESPACE2::begin;
    using MY_NAMESPACE2::end;
}


int main()
{
    MY_NAMESPACE1::my_cls* p;

    for(auto i : p)
    {
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Basically, if I use no namespace by setting USE_NAMESPACE as 0 or if both are using same namesapce the code compiles. otherwise getting an error

```
source_file.cpp:106:16: error: invalid range expression of type .... no viable 'begin' function available
```

Can someone please let me know if this is expected or why this throws an error?

Comment: Include the code you're having the problem with in the question.

Comment: MSVC is doing something wrong, by looking up `begin` in context of namespace `std`. It should be looked up in the context of the loop, by ADL alone. And since `MY_NAMESPACE2` is not an associated namespace of `MY_NAMESPACE1::my_cls*`, it is properly not found.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm code is there in the link, embedded for quicker reference.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Can you please elaborate, my_cls is being referenced with namespace so shouldnt it be automatically resolved within the from the iterator ?

Comment: `my_cls` is being referenced with a namespace, yes - but `begin` taking it is in a different namespace.